# Oracle PLSQL record type declared in package specification seems "lost"

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

There is package specification in schema A

```
...
TYPE usr_attr_type IS RECORD (
 id       NUMBER(20),
 login    VARCHAR2(256),
 attr     VARCHAR2(256),
 val      VARCHAR2(256));
...
```

Compilation error:

```
Error: ORA-04043: object SYS_PLSQL_B8998708_57_1 does not exist
```

But, for unknown reasons object `SYS_PLSQL_B8998708_57_1` (with **almost same** structure) exists in schema B.

```
create or replace type SYS_PLSQL_B8998708_57_1 
as object (
ID NUMBER(20),
LOGIN VARCHAR2(256 BYTE),
ATTR VARCHAR2(256 BYTE),
VAL VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE));
```

What should I do to correct this error and where I can find dependency description between type, declared in PLSQL and type, created by Oracle engine?

Comment: Are you trying to access _schemaA_ objects from _schemaB_ (or vice-versa) ?

Comment: @Abra not at all. I've just searched through all schemes to find mystical object and found it in another scheme. Seems like packages was moved or something like this.

Comment: _where I can find dependency description between [PL/SQL] type ... and [Object] type_ What kind of _dependency description_ are you hoping to find?

Comment: @Abra I'm not hundred percent sure, but if Oracle looks for sys_plsql type during the compilation, does it mean that engine know something about some kind of link between record type and sys_plsql type? Why it searched for this type, that doesnt mention in package?

Comment: Which version of 12c are you using? This reminds me of I bug I stumbled across a few years back on an early 12c first release. It was a development database with developers dropping and recreating schema objects all the time: Oracle seemed to get confused by all these different instances of the same packaged types in different schemas. There was a patch from Oracle Support which fixed it.

Comment: @APC Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production